# How to manage admin authentication with Oauth flow to Microsoft Graph API in Rails App

Tags: admin, microsoft-graph-api

I am deeply struggling to find the right flow. I have a rails app, registered on Microsft App portal (with Id, Pwd and Scopes). To be be as simple as possible : I need to have access through my app to all emails (only read) of a company. It is a server app, which processes informations during the night.

What I understood and tried :

Get a login link for the administrator of the company :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={MY_APP_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=MY_APP_ADDRESS&response_mode=query&prompt=admin_consent
```

In callback, I do get a code in params. From that code, I get a token with a POST request, specifying :

```
client_id: MY_APP_ID,
grant_type: "authorization_code",
code: MY_RECEIVED_CODE,
redirect_uri: MY_APP_ADDRESS,
client_secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
```

From that I get a Token. A simple request to get messages works well for the administrator mailbox (the one who validated the access) ; 'Access is denied' when I try for any other person from the organization.

Last point. Scopes defined in Microsoft App portal : Group.Read.All and Mail.Read (both for apps or delegated services)

What is the right way to get that done ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

add the query parameter prompt=admin_consent to the authorization request, that way the admin will consent on behalf of the entire organization and not just for his/herself.